# HttpServletResponse issue.setCharacterEncoding: Depend attribute is not supported by modern compiler

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

In my java class I am trying to do something like

```
HttpServletResponse.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
```

but the code fails to compile with the message:

> *Depend attribute is not supported by modern compiler.*

If I remove this line, code compiles without any issues.

Can anyone shed any light on this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

[HttpServletResponse.setCharacterEncoding()](http://java.sun.com/products/servlet/2.5/docs/servlet-2_5-mr2/javax/servlet/ServletResponse.html#setCharacterEncoding(java.lang.String)) is not a static method. You need to call it on an instance. Something like: (assuming your instance is called `resp`)

```
resp.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
```

Alternatively, you could set character encoding in the `Content-type` header like this:

```
resp.setContentType("text/html; charset=UTF-8")
```

EDIT: Ok, by your comments, I see you are already doing this. I took the wording of the question literally. Anyway, the problem is most likely that you are using `javac` with dependency tracking turned on. It's a flag you can pass on the command line (or an attribute to the `<javac>` ant task). Turn off dependency tracking. It's not supported by Sun's compiler.

Comment: Why it doesn't say the usual thing: *"non static attribute may not be called from non static context"* ( or something like that ) It it for the compiler version?

Comment: The OP must be compiling with dependency tracking turned on. It's a flag you can pass on the command line (or in the javac ant task). It's not supported by Sun's compiler.

Comment: I am actually using an instance of HttpServletResponse. I just typed in HttpServletResponse.setCharact.... to make the class/object name absolutely create but it ended it up creating more confusion. So to be clear..  I am using something like

 resp.setCharacterEncoding(...);

where resp is an instance of HttpServletResponse

Comment: @makhan10: Ok, I updated my answer in response to your comment.

Comment: The normal approach sets the encoding of the response writer. Your "alternative" approach doesn't do that. It only sets the encoding which the client is supposed to use. This is a major difference.

Comment: @BalusC: That's not exactly true. From the docs for HttpServletResponse.setContentType(): "The response's character encoding is only set from the given content type if this method is called before getWriter is called." -- http://java.sun.com/products/servlet/2.5/docs/servlet-2%5F5-mr2/javax/servlet/ServletResponse.html#setContentType(java.lang.String)

Comment: @BalusC: Also, from the docs for setCharacterEncoding(): " has no effect if it is called after getWriter has been called". And "Calling setContentType(java.lang.String) with the String of text/html and calling this method with the String of UTF-8 is equivalent with calling setContentType with the String of text/html; charset=UTF-8." So I think the normal and alternative method are truly interchangeable.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try to remove the `-depend` option when invoking `javac` (which is not supported by modern compiler :).